# An example of a Foldable which is not a Functor (or not Traversable)?

Tags: haskell, functor, fold, traversal

A [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) instance is likely to be some sort of container, and so is likely to be a `Functor` as well. Indeed, [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldable_and_Traversable) says

> A `Foldable` type is also a container (although the class does not technically require `Functor`, interesting `Foldable`s are all `Functor`s).

So is there an example of a `Foldable` which is not naturally a `Functor` or a `Traversable`? (which perhaps the Haskell wiki page missed :-) )

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here's a fully parametric example:

```
data Weird a = Weird a (a -> a)

instance Foldable Weird where
  foldMap f (Weird a b) = f $ b a
```

`Weird` is not a `Functor` because `a` occurs in a negative position.

Comment: Oh, nice! Didn't even think of that. Wonder if there are any `Foldable` instances in standard-ish libraries that fail to be a `Functor` due to contravariance?

Comment: I think you could do it with certain extensions and type synonyms.

Comment: How about `instance Functor Weird where fmap fn (Weird a aa) = Weird (fn (aa a)) id`?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Nice one! But it does not satisfy the functor laws. `fmap id  ==  id`

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher depends. Technically speaking `Free` doesn't satisfy the monad laws w.r.t. definitional equality and in the same way `pipes` satisfy appropriate laws only through the `observe` prism. So definitional equality might be not the most sensible/useful/natural one (take quotients e.g. for which definitional equality becomes an annoying artifact of a language you use). Now your `Weird` looks a lot like `Coyoneda`. And your `foldMap` have a very similar and specific semantics: it treats `Weird` as a one-element container and always applies that stored function.

Comment: So as soon as you always extract the element from `Weird` as `runWeird (Weird x f) = f x`, the functor laws do hold through the `runWeird` prism.

Answer (score 55):

Here's an easy example: `Data.Set.Set`. [See for yourself.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Data-Set.html)

The reason for this should be apparent if you examine the types of the specialized `fold` and `map` functions defined for `Set`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Set a -> b

map :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

Because the data structure relies on a binary search tree internally, an `Ord` constraint is needed for elements. `Functor` instances must allow any element type, so that's not viable, alas.

Folding, on the other hand, always destroys the tree to produce the summary value, so there's no need to sort the intermediate results of the fold. Even if the fold is actually building a new `Set`, the responsibility for satisfying the `Ord` constraint lies on the accumulation function passed to the fold, not the fold itself.

The same will probably apply to any container type that's not fully parametric. And given the utility of `Data.Set`, this makes the remark you quoted about "interesting" `Foldable`s seem a bit suspect, I think!

Comment: This is indeed an example of a `Foldable` which cannot be made a `Functor`. However, this seems to be more due to the fact that Haskell's type system cannot express "`Set` makes sense only for `Ord` types, and to make something a `Functor` one only needs to define `fmap` for the types which makes sense, as defined elsewhere", than due to something inherent about what `Set` and `Functor` represent. Thanks for the example, anyway. :-)

Comment: @Prateek: Yes and no. Being fully parametric is very much inherent to what `Functor` represents. That said, a more expressive type system than standard Haskell (including the full type system supported by GHC, actually) could express "fully parametric over some class of types", which is what would be desired here.

Comment: @Prateek: In a more mathematical sense, `Functor` only encompasses specific kinds of functors, from the category of all Haskell types onto a proper subcategory of itself. It can't express functors that operate only on subcategories, or other things that would otherwise make sense. That said, Sjoerd Visscher's example remains both more interesting and more esoteric than mine. :]

Comment: If we are willing to live with `Set` stuff working only for `Ord` types (even though sets in mathematics have no such constraints), we should be willing to tolerate the same imperfection in `Functor` too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Set` doesn't inherently require `Ord` at all times, only when you are "inspecting" it such as by checking the length, displaying it as a string, or getting the minimum / maximum element etc. So if you allowed `Set` to in some situations (e.g `(+) <$> set`) not have `Ord`, and then have it only condense and reorder itself whenever it does have that `Ord` constraint (so yes this cannot be done in standard Haskell, but I'm thinking more from a theoretical/math standpoint). Then you could have `Set` be a true `Functor`, and even an `Applicative` and a `Monad`.

Comment: I like this answer, because it provides a reasonable argument against the seemingly reasonable requirement that `Functor` be a superclass of `Foldable`.

Answer (score 27):

Reading [Beautiful folding](http://squing.blogspot.fr/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html) 
I realized that any `Foldable` can be made a `Functor` by wrapping it into

```
data Store f a b = Store (f a) (a -> b)
```

with a simple smart contructor:

```
store :: f a -> Store f a a
store x = Store x id
```

(This is just a variant of the [Store](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/3.0/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Store.html) comonad data type.)

Now we can define

```
instance Functor (Store f a) where
    fmap f (Store x g)   = Store x (f . g)

instance (F.Foldable f) => F.Foldable (Store f a) where
    foldr f z (Store x g)    = F.foldr (f . g) z x
```

This way, we can make both `Data.Set.Set` and Sjoerd Visscher's `Weird` a functor. (However, since the structure doesn't memoize its values, repeatedly folding over it could be very inefficient, if the function that we used in `fmap` is complex.)

---

**Update:** This also provides an example of a structure that is a functor, foldable but not traversable. To make `Store` traversable, we would need to make `(->) r` traversable. So we'd need to implement

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => (r -> (f a)) -> f (r -> a)
```

Let's take `Either b` for `f`. Then we'd need to implement

```
sequenceA' :: (r -> Either b a) -> Either b (r -> a)
```

Clearly, there is no such function (you can verify with [Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn)). So we can neither realize `sequenceA`.

Comment: The Store data type is exactly the free functor over any type constructor, also known as Coyoneda (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-4.2.3/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html).

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe Not exactly.  `Coyoneda` is existentially quantified where `Store` is not.