# Why does the Functor type class not include a fold method?

Tags: haskell

Why does the type class `Functor` have only the member`fmap`? I often find it useful to perform a fold over datatypes. Say, hierarchical ones, like a tree.

Note that a `map` is a special case of `fold`, that is, the latter is more fundamental. I guess I can take it the way it is, but maybe there is a reason?

Comment: How would you define `fold` on `IO`, which is a `Functor`, but not `Foldable`?

Comment: How is `fmap` a special case of `fold`?  I can't imagine how you would be able to implement either in terms of the other, which is what I think of when I think of "more fundamental".

Comment: the `fmap` in my post was a typo. I mean `map`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because a `Functor` is a very general kind of object; not all `Functor`s support folds.  For example, there is an instance<sup>[1](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/recursion-schemes/catamorphisms)</sup>

```
instance Functor (a ->) where
     -- > fmap :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
     fmap f g = g . f
```

But, while `(a ->)` is a `Functor` for all `a`, for infinite `a` there isn't a reasonable `fold` definition.  (Incidentally, a 'fold' in general is a [catamorphism](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/recursion-schemes/catamorphisms), which means it has a different type for each functor.  The `Foldable` type class defines it for sequence-like types.).

Consider what the `foldr` definition for `Integer -> Integer` would look like; what would the outermost application be?  What would the value of

```
foldr (\ _ n -> 1 + n) 0 (\ n -> n + 1)
```

be?  There isn't a reasonable definition of `fold` without a lot more structure on the argument type.

<sup>[1](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/recursion-schemes/catamorphisms)</sup> `(a ->)` isn't legal Haskell for some reason.  But I'm going to use it anyway as a more readable version of `(->) a`, since I think it's easier for a novice to understand.

Comment: I think I see where I was wrong: `map` is a special case of `fold` only for lists (maybe for something else) but not in general. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, `fold` is way more powerful on lists than on other types (especially something like arbitrary trees).

Formally (ignoring laziness), the list functor is the free monoid functor, which is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from monoids to sets; the general `fold` function is then one direction of the hom-set adjunction between the list functor and the forgetful functor.

As such, every monoid homomorphism on lists (which includes `map`) is given by some instance of `fold`.

Answer (score 8):

The abstraction you are looking for is [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html): This is a type class providing variuos forms of `fold`.

There is also  [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html) for things where you can “fold while changing”, comparable to the `mapAccumL` function for lists.

It is actually not true that `fmap` is a special case of `fold`, as pointed out by @DietrichEpp, see as here are [possible non-Functor instances of Foldable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359115/haskell-an-example-of-a-foldable-which-is-not-a-functor-or-not-traversable).

`map` is however a special case of `mapAccumL` (no surprise, given the name), and hence the definition of `Traversable` requires the thing to be also a `Functor` and a `Foldable`.

Comment: thanks. this is interesting. I am a beginner, I vaguely understand what you are saying. in general, though, it seems confusing that a `Functor` is not necessarily a `Foldable`. Given that `map` is defined in terms of `fold`...

Comment: That's exactly the reason, though: if *`fold` were defined in terms of `map`*, then we could define `fold` for every `Functor`, since we could use the existing `map` to get `fold` for free.

Comment: @DietrichEpp's hinting the right thing; there are [possible non-Functor instances of Foldable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359115/haskell-an-example-of-a-foldable-which-is-not-a-functor-or-not-traversable).

Comment: Sorry, confused `fold` with `traverse`; fixed the answer accordingly.