# What are some types that discriminate between categories?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

I'm still getting familiar with all this category theory stuff, and just about every example I see is with a Maybe or an Array. But I haven't found any examples that discriminate between these categories. For example, here are some of the questions I've still been unable to answer:

1. whats a Semigroup that isn't also a Monoid?
2. whats a Foldable that isn't also a Traversable? [[Duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359115/haskell-an-example-of-a-foldable-which-is-not-a-functor-or-not-traversable)
3. whats an Functor that isn't also an Apply?
4. whats an Apply that isn't also an Applicative?
5. whats an Apply that isn't also a Chain?
6. whats a Chain that isn't also a Monad?
7. what an Applicative that isn't also a Monad? [[Duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad)

I'm learning this stuff through the context of [JavaScript FantasyLand](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) so that's where I'm getting the lingo from -- I understand there are different words for these things.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what a `Chain` is. That's not a terribly well-known class.

Comment: Maps are instances of `Apply` but not of `Applicative`.

Comment: @dfeuer, perhaps `Chain` is `Monad` without `return`.

Comment: @user3237465, sounds likely. I know those by Kmett's name, `Bind`. I've never looked at instances though.

Comment: @dfeuer I maked one question as duplicate -- the other question isnt as granular  -- it asks whats a functor that isnt an applicative. I want to know about Apply as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could add links to the definitions at Hackage for the lesser known types such as `Apply` or `Chain`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, it seems `Chain` is a term used in some JavaScript library. I'm speculating it might be equivalent to `Bind` from `semigroupoids`, but I really don't feel like digging into JS to figure that out.

Comment: Fantasyland talks about some synonyms. `Bind` is one of them, I think its the plunger in Haskell `=<<`.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Whats a Semigroup that isn't also a Monoid?

Cactus gives a great example of a semigroup that's not a monoid. Non-empty (finite) lists of any type represent the *free semigroup* over that type. Another example is `Data.Void.Void`, which isn't a `Monoid` because it doesn't have any elements and therefore doesn't have an identity element. Yet another example is the set of positive integers under addition.

#### 3. Whats an Functor that isn't also an Apply?

One `Functor` that's not an `Apply` is  `Handler`.

```
data Handler a where
  Handler :: Exception e => (e -> IO a) -> Handler a

instance Functor Handler where
  fmap f (Handler h) = Handler (\e -> f <$> h e)
```

Given `Handler f :: Handler (a -> b)` and `Handler g :: Handler a`, you have

```
f :: e1 -> IO (a -> b)
g :: e2 -> IO a
```

Where `e1` and `e2` are (possibly different) types of exception. You need to create `h :: e3 -> IO b` for some exception type `e3`. There is no really *sensible* way to do this**.

It seems harder to find `Functor`s that *can't* be made into law-abiding `Apply` instances, because `Apply` has just one law and therefore admits all sorts of weird things that `Applicative` would reject.

#### 4. Whats an Apply that isn't also an Applicative?

#### 6. What an Applicative that isn't also a Monad?

`Map k` and `IntMap`. Also, `(,) a` and `Const a` when `a` is a `Semigroup` but not a `Monoid`. Similarly, some other types fit the pattern of accepting a weaker context for `Apply` and/or `Bind` than for `Applicative` or `Monad`, respectively.

#### 5. Whats an Apply that isn't also a Chain?

`ZipList` is an `Apply` but not a `Bind`. I don't know what a `Chain` is.

---

** One semi-sensible way might look like this:

```
data P x y = P x y deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance (Exception x, Exception y) =>
            Exception (P x y)
instance Apply Handler where
  Handler f <.> Handler g =
    Handler (\(P e1 e2) -> f e1 <*> g e2)
```

I *think* this obeys the `Apply` law, but I'm not yet completely certain.

Answer (score 3):

Non-empty lists, defined as `data NEList a = Cons a [a]` are semigroups but not monoids.