# Concrete Type Example of a Functor that Fails to be an Applicative?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

From [functors that are not applicatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220436/good-examples-of-not-a-functor-functor-applicative-monad):

> **A type constructor which is a Functor but not an Applicative.** A simple example is a pair:
>
> ```
> instance Functor ((,) r) where
>     fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)
> ```
>
> But there is no way how to define its `Applicative` instance without imposing additional restrictions on `r`. In particular, there is no way how to define `pure :: a -> (r, a)` for an arbitrary `r`.

Here, `pure` fails to be definable for *all types at once*; however, for any **concrete** type `T`, one can make `((,) T)` an applicative.

**Question:** Is there an example of a concrete functor (i.e., no type variables involved) that is a functor but not an applicative?

Comment: "[However], for any concrete type `T`, one can make `((,) T)` an applicative" -- not really. You still need `T` to be a monoid, and not just because of `pure`: you also need to implement `(<*>)` in a way that the two methods follow the applicative laws.

Comment: So all that is needed to answer this question is to find a non-monoid `T` and then `((,) T)` will be a concrete functor that fails to be an applicative?

Comment: Yup, that is enough.

Comment: There's a theorem in mathematics that any collection with at least 2 elements can be made into a monoid.  So for any concrete type `T`, it could in principle be made a member of `Monoid`, and then could in principle be made `Applicative`.  What's wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Is `Dead` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220865/3072788) what you are looking for? There are no additional type variables...

Comment: This answer is along the lines you've started thinking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440023/414413

Comment: A simple example of a functor that is not applicative is (a -> Int) -> Maybe a. The type required for <*> has no implementation that satisfies the identity laws.

Comment: @winitzki: how is `(a -> Int) -> Maybe a` a `Functor` (i.e. how do you define `fmap`)?

Comment: @Tom `deriving Functor` should do that automatically. This type constructor uses `a` in covariant positions, so it's clearly a functor. A functor instance can be constructed mechanically. If you see how `(a -> Int) -> Int` and `z -> Maybe a` implement their `fmap`s, you can then easily see what to do here.

Comment: @winitzki: But of course, thanks! For those interested, the idea is that given a function `f :: a -> b` and a function `b -> Int` they can be composed to give a function `a -> Int`. Given `x :: (a -> Int) -> Maybe a` one can apply it on the result and get a `Maybe a`, which can then be mapped using `Maybe`'s `fmap` to a `Maybe b`, that is `fmap f x = \g -> fmap f (x (g . f))`.

Comment: @winitzki: now the question is how it can be proven that no `<*>` implementation for the type could possibly satisfy the laws.

Comment: @Tom First, you derive an implementation from the type. It is simpler to consider `zip : F a -> F b -> F (a,b)` rather than `<*>`. Now, we need to implement `zip : ((a -> Z) -> Maybe a)) -> ((b -> Z) -> Maybe b) -> ((a, b) -> Z) -> Maybe (a, b)`. But a function with this type signature can only return `Nothing`, because there is no way of ever computing a pair `(a, b)` (we cannot have a value of type `a -> Z` or `b -> Z`, we only have `(a, b) -> Z`). So this is the only implementation. However, a `zip` method that always returns `Nothing` will violate identity laws for applicative functors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @winitzki!

Answer (score 5):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment here, so I'll try to do it as an answer:

> however, for any concrete type T, one can make ((,) T) an applicative.

...

> There's a theorem in mathematics that any collection with at least 2 elements can be made into a monoid. So for any concrete type T, it could in principle be made a member of Monoid, and then could in principle be made Applicative. What's wrong with this reasoning?

What about the tuple from the uninhabited type? `(,) Void`

It is a `Functor`,right?

Could you derive `Applicative` for it? How would `pure` be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

There is nice example in [reactive-banana library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana).

It features `Event a` types, which represents a single simultaneous event in time (think, an impulse), and `Behavior a` type, which represents a value that is available in any moment (for instance, emitting a value from the last event).

Behavior is an Applicative, because you **can combine** two of them - they have a value in any point of time.

[image]

Event, though, is a Functor only, because  you **can't combine** them. Given two `Event`s you can't be sure they will happen simultaneosly.

[image: Event]

Comment: [_Push-Pull FRP_](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf) gives a `Monad` instance for `Event` which implements dynamic event switching. The corresponding `Applicative` instance takes the Cartesian product of the two events.

Answer (score 0):

> > "[However], for any concrete type `T`, one can make `((,) T)` an applicative" -- not really. You still need `T` to be a monoid, and not just because of pure: you also need to implement `(<*>)` in a way that the two methods follow the applicative laws.
>
> [...]
>
> There's a theorem in mathematics that any collection with at least 2 elements can be made into a monoid. So for any concrete type `T`, it could in principle be made a member of `Monoid`, and then could in principle be made `Applicative`. What's wrong with this reasoning?

The "in principle" doesn't necessarily translate into code. Consider:

```
newtype UserID = UserID Integer
```

As far as I can see, there is no meaningful `Monoid` instance for `UserID`. In principle, one might use `0` and `(+)` on the underlying `Integer`, but that would amount to leaking an implementation detail for no good reason (and which is likely end up being hidden by making the type abstract). That being so, `(,) UserID` would be a perfectly good example of a `Functor` which is not an `Applicative`.