# Why does Foldable inherit from Functor in Frege?

Tags: types, frege

In Haskell, the class `Foldable` is standalone i.e.

```
class Foldable t where ...
```

However, in Frege:

```
class Functor t => Foldable t where ...
```

Why was this constraint introduced? What ill-formed programs/ideas can it rule out?

It prevented me from defining an `instance Foldable HashSet`, where `HashSet` is a custom data type which wraps `Data.HashMap` to provide a set-based interface. (It can be worked around by applying `toList` first, so it's not a serious issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess that it used to be the case that Haskell's Foldable did have Functor as a superclass once and that Frege inherited the Foldable code at this time. Could've been 2012 or so.

I'm not sure I understand your concern as Data.HashMap *is* indeed a Functor. But anyway, I invite you to design a patch and make a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I opened a [PR](https://github.com/Frege/frege/pull/334).

Answer (score 3):

I think this discussion give you the whole feedback on the topic (especially part about Sets) [Haskell : An example of a Foldable which is not a Functor (or not Traversable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359115/haskell-an-example-of-a-foldable-which-is-not-a-functor-or-not-traversable)

Comment: In terms why Frege chooses to limit its `Foldable`s to `Functor`s - I don't know